# Link problems in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: openssl, visual-studio-2022

I am working on porting some proprietary software from OpenSSL 1.1.1 to OpenSSL 3.0.8, but I'm running into a problem. The application is multithreaded and written to compile under Visual Studio 2022.

The libraries I'm including are:

Comctl32.lib, libssl_static.lib, libcrypto_static.lib;crypt32.lib, ws2_32.lib, GDI32.LIB, ADVAPI32.LIB, USER32.LIB

The last three libraries are required, according to the OpenSSL documentation, when linking against the static libraries. Not including those three does NOT clear the warning or the error. I would seem to be missing a library that I need to include.

Depending on whether the static OpenSSL is happy with multithreaded applications, I should be able to ignore the warnings - although it would be better if I could avoid multiple copies of code. What I can't ignore are the errors.

The documentation for OpenSSL 3.0.8 states that it should be a simple migration from OpenSSL 1.1.1. Since it compiled against the static libraries with 1.1.1, I expected this to compile easily against the static libraries for 3.0.8.

I have tried compiling against the dynamic libraries for 3.0.8 and that works fine - it links and runs - but work has placed a requirement that the binary be statically compiled. This is what is producing the error.

Simply put, then, the libraries included are incorrect. There's a wrong version being used somewhere. Can someone help in figuring out what the library line should be?

The initial warnings (I've only included a few):

LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__time32' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(time.obj)' is imported by 'libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-http_client.obj)' in function '_OSSL_HTTP_REQ_CTX_set_request_line'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '__time32' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(time.obj)' is imported by 'libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-bss_conn.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '__time32' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(time.obj)' is imported by 'libcrypto_static.lib(libdefault-lib-drbg.obj)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__time32' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(time.obj)' is imported by 'libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-bio_lib.obj)' in function '_BIO_do_connect_retry'

The errors I'm getting are:

1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-params_from_text.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-dso_win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-asn1_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-ctrl_params_translate.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-x509_obj.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-evp_key.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-pem_lib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__strspn referenced in function _PEM_get_EVP_CIPHER_INFO
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-v3_asid.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strspn
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-v3_addr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strspn
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-bio_addr.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc referenced in function _WspiapiClone@8
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-conf_sap.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___strdup referenced in function _OPENSSL_config
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-conf_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___strdup
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-bss_file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__feof referenced in function _file_ctrl
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-ui_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__feof
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-bss_file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ferror referenced in function _file_read
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-ui_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ferror
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-bss_file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fgets referenced in function _file_gets
1>libcrypto_static.lib(libcrypto-lib-ui_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fgets
1>MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4

Answer (score 0):

Try using the /VERBOSE linker option to get more detailed information about the linker errors. This may help you identify which libraries are causing the problems.

reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/verbose-print-progress-messages?view=msvc-170

Comment: 1>    Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\lib\x86\MSVCRT.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x86\libucrtd.lib:

This might be where it's loading two CRT libraries, I don't know enough about Windows naming conventions to be sure.

The verbose is making clearer that the static OpenSSL libraries are not picking up all of the functions they need from the included libraries, but I'm not really any further in understanding what I need to include.

Comment: so back to the original warning "defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB"
maybe try /NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nodefaultlib-ignore-libraries?view=msvc-170 and see how it goes?